# Is there a way to know if related objects have been prefetched?

Tags: django, django-models

Is there any way to know whether related objects have been prefetched from inside a model instance?

Suppose one has

```
class Order( models.Model):
    ...

    def is_all_in_stock( self):
       # how to do this?


class LineItem( models.Order):
    order = models.ForeignKey( Order, ..., related_name='line_items')
    stock = models.ForeignKey( Stock, ...)
    ...
```

And one wants to generate some report of all orders that are delayed for assorted reasons

```
for order in orders:  # orders is a queryset
     ...
     out_of_stock = any([ line.stock.status != IN_STOCK 
           for line in order.line_items.all() ])
```

This is efficient if one is iterating over a queryset that did `.prefetch_related( "line_items", "line_items__stock)`. It doesn't hit the DB at all. It hammers the DB if not.

On the other hand, using a queryset like

```
out_of_stock = order.line_items.exclude( stock__status = IN_STOCK ).exists()
```

hits the DB only once for each order, the classic N+1 problem

Is it possible to write the method  `order.is_all_in_stock(self)` to take advantage of what has been prefetched if it has been prefetched, and to fall back on running a  query each time it is called if not?

Comment: You can verify it with a tool like django-debug-toolbar, which e.g. shows how many and which queries are executed for a request. Highly recommended! https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Yes, I'm using it. But I'd like to write that method so it can find out for itself whether it can rely on prefetched data or not. Two methods for the two situations seems inelegant.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. (Not perfect if the underscore denotes an internal undocumented feature subject to change without warning, but I can write a test to spot that)

Comment: Great. Yeah, you are correct that this is not part of the public API, so use with care. But I am guessing this is the only way to do it.